# Mysql+PHP problem

Tags: php, mysql

This is my "person" table:

```
eid sex email   
17  Female  example@example.com
```

This is my php page:

```
<?php
$loginquery = mysql_query('SELECT eid, email, sex FROM person WHERE email = "'example@example.com'" ;') or die("Query fail: " . mysql_error() );
$userlogin = mysql_fetch_array($loginquery);

if($userlogin){
$_SESSION['eid']= $userlogin['eid'];
$_SESSION['email']= $userlogin['email'];
$_SESSION['sex']= $userlogin['sex'];
}


echo "user ".$_SESSION['eid']." ".$_SESSION['email']." ".$_SESSION['sex']; 
?>
```

This is the output:

user  example@example.com Female

Why the `$_SESSION['eid']` is not printed ?

Comment: You should have a syntax error when using `'` as the MySQL string delimiter inside of the `'` for PHP's string delimiter.

Comment: i belive that was a typo here

Comment: Is it something weird like the query failing and therefore the `if` statement not being satisfied, and then the $_SESSION variables keeping their old values (I don't know how $_SESSION works I'm afraid) and perhaps you previously didn't have `eid` in the query? But I fear what I've just said is likely to be nonsense :)

Comment: try var_dump($_SESSION['eid']) to see if it contains anything

Comment: what does `var_dump($userlogin)` give u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least 2 bugs

`session_start();` is not called and it should.

The query is weird:

```
$loginquery = mysql_query('SELECT eid, email, sex FROM person WHERE email = "'example@example.com'" ;') or die("Query fail: " . mysql_error() );
```

I don't know why this does not produce an error, but your string is not build well. Try something like

```
$loginquery = mysql_query("SELECT eid, email, sex FROM person WHERE email = 'example@example.com';") or die("Query fail: " . mysql_error() );
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and it works: 
 **sqlErr() is my own function for error handling**

```
$dbcon=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or sqlErr();
@mysql_select_db("test",$dbcon) or sqlErr();

$loginquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE email = 'example@example.com' ;") or die("Query fail: " . mysql_error() );
$userlogin = mysql_fetch_array($loginquery,MYSQL_ASSOC);

if($userlogin){
$_SESSION['eid']= $userlogin['eid'];
$_SESSION['email']= $userlogin['email'];
$_SESSION['sex']= $userlogin['sex'];
}


echo "user ".$_SESSION['eid']." ".$_SESSION['email']." ".$_SESSION['sex'];
```